# Exposed filter show results

Tags: views

[image]I have a content type say sample. I've created a view page to slideshow all sample content type. I have an exposed filter at the top of the page, people search using id there, on searching it is giving the correct result with the slider but the slider is'nt working at the result page. I want it show the result first and then the others.

Is it possible.

[image]

Comment: Just make this filter `Required`

Comment: @NikhilM I've made it required, It is'nt showing anything now under the preview.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your Views settings? And maybe the current result also?

Comment: @ScottAnderson Done...

Comment: Any JS errors in console? Also do you have Theme Developer module installed?

Comment: @ScottAnderson How to check for JS errors in console. No I'm not using theme developer module.

Comment: You may need to install Firebug extension for Firefox, then right click on the page and select 'Inspect Element with Firebug', then click the Console tab http://i.imgur.com/eSG0zHE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the Use Ajax option under the Other Tab..

Comment: I've anabled ajax, I'm getting the result but other slides are not showing up.